# why calling dbContext.Database.Migrate() doesn't throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

the sample code is below:

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();  // <---------I accidentally calls it again
}
```

so I accidentally calls the `Migrate()` method twice, but to my suprise, it doesn't throw any excetpion, does `Migrate()` check if the underlying database is created? if it is created then abort the migration and return normally?

Comment: That's actually the key idea of migration - all executed migrations are stored in special database table, so each migration runs only once

Comment: What is `GenerateMigrationToFolder`? This is the first time I have heard about generating runtime migrations. Is this a common use case for you?

Comment: @JonasH not a common use case. ok, don't worry about the `GenerateMigrationToFolder` thing, could you tell me why the second call of `dataContext.Database.Migrate()` doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: @Quercus  I edited the question and don't worry about the Generate Migration in run time, so why the second call of dataContext.Database.Migrate() doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: As Quercus says, the EntityFramework checks the `__EFMigrationHistory` table for already applied migrations, and only applies missing migrations, and these migrations are added to the table. So migrations are *idempotent*.

Comment: `Database.Migrate()` is the runtime equivalent of `Update-Database` PMC (or its cli equivalent) command, hence does not need to throw exceptions if the database is already up-to-date, its simply no-op.